# How to find set of lowest sum of distinct column elements in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Problem statement: There are 5 projects and 15 employees and the numbers against each column shows the interest of each employee in a given project. Each project can have a maximum of 3 employees. Scores are from 1-5 1 being the highest preference and 5 being the lowest preference. I have to divide the employees among the projects in such a way that least number of people get dissatisfied or minimum score. Note that my algorithm creates all possible combinations and then sorts those combinations with sum in ascending order and picks up top 5 combinations with distinct employees.

But here is the problem, so, for example, my sortedsum matrix is [1,1,1,4,9,9,...] now this algorithmically is correct, but the thing is if I pick top 5 of them my total sum will be 16. But there could be a possibility where instead of taking [1,1,1,4,9] if I take [2,1,1,4] as the first four then the fifth project team sum goes to 3 and in that way the minimum will change and here's the point where my algorithm fails.

I have a 3nXn matrix, for this example, I will take it as a 15x5:
So the matrix looks like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/omcq7.png):

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""

employee  proj_A  proj_B  proj_C  proj_D  proj_E
      A1       1       5       3       4       2
      B1       5       4       1       2       3
      C1       2       3       4       1       5
      A2       4       2       1       3       5
      B2       4       5       3       2       1
      C2       3       1       2       5       4
      A3       1       2       4       3       5
      B3       2       3       1       5       4
      C3       5       3       4       1       2
      A4       4       5       3       2       1
      B4       5       3       4       2       1
      C4       1       2       3       4       5
      A5       1       3       2       5       4
      B5       2       1       3       5       4
      C5       2       1       4       5       4

      """), sep=r"\s+")
```

*[formatted to make it easy to paste into the shell]*

The problem I want to solve is to pick three distinct elements in each column, distinct meaning from distinct rows in such a way that their sum taken together for all 5 column remains the least.

For example, here if I pick A1,B1,C1 for A and then A2,B2,C2 for B and so on then the sum which is 1+5+2=8 for A and 2+5+1=8 for B and so on when added together i.e. 8+8+... should be the minimum sum of all possible combinations. Note that if A1, B1 and C1 are assigned to A they can't switch to B or any other next column.

What I tried was created all possible combinations starting from A1, B1, C1 to A5, B5 and C5 and computed their sums and sorted it in increasing order and picked first five which had distinct elements as shown below:

Limitations with my code:
1. It takes so much time for the matrix I am optimizing (which is a 30x10 matrix) as the combinations are way too much.
2. It will ignore any scenario where by compromising the scores for the initial elements to a littlebit higher, we may get the mid-scores which can be reduced a lot.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("csvfile.csv")
teamsize=3
employes=data["Name"]
PScore=[]
for i in range(10):
    PScore.append(data[f"Project {i+1}"])
Scorings_combo=[]
for i in range(len(employes)):
    for j in range(len(employes)):
        for k in range(len(employes)):
            for l in range(10):
                if i==j or j==k or k==i:
                    break
                score=0
                score=score+PScore[l][i]+PScore[l][j]+PScore[l][k]
                Scorings_combo.append([i+1,j+1,k+1,l+1,score])
a=[Scorings_combo[i][4]for i in range(len(Scorings_combo))]
#b=sorted(a,reverse=True)
b=sorted(a)
emps=[]
sig=1
empl=[]
passigned=[]
countee=0
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(3):
        if Scorings_combo[a.index(b[i])][j] in emps or Scorings_combo[a.index(b[i])][3] in passigned:
            a[a.index(b[i])]=-1
            sig=0
            break
    if sig!=0:
        print("New")
        for k in range(3):emps.append(Scorings_combo[a.index(b[i])][k])
        empl.append(Scorings_combo[a.index(b[i])])
        passigned.append(Scorings_combo[a.index(b[i])][3])
        countee=countee+1
        if count==8:
            break
    sig=1
    print(f"Iteration:{i}/{len(b)}")
```

For example:
3,3,3,4,9 
will be the solution even if the following is possible:
4,4,4,4,4
because it will look for the descending order distinct elements which gives me the first solution.

Kindly do help me if you have any ideas. Thanks

Here is the drive link to the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yaswBEi3RzrhQ743hJTnUeZFZNo-QBBR/view?usp=sharing

Here's a simpler example:
Matrix=[[1,2],[2,1],[1,2],[1,2],[2,1],[1,2]]
Now minimum possible combination is: for the first column: [1,1,1] and [1,1,2] for the second column.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212660/discussion-on-question-by-shivam-sahil-how-to-find-set-of-lowest-sum-of-distinc).

Comment: Shivam, I posted another solution to this modeled after the 'stable marriage problem'. It's a better approach than using genetic algorithms in my opinion, but like the genetic algorithm approach it introduces some randomness into the assignment process and applies a sort of 'fitness' score to them. Runnable code:  https://pastebin.com/kVj0FuJP

Comment: I see, thank you very much will be looking into it too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to experiment with genetic algorithms, and this seemed like a good optimization type problem to apply it to. With 15 rows that could be in any order, there's 15! permutations, or 1.0e+12. A brute-force approach to try all permutations isn't practical.

I have the function below that calculates the "fitness" of the individuals in the population. The score is a combination of the mean and standard deviation. My math might not be entirely sound and I'm definitely winging it with numpy, but it does seem to produce good results.

```
def calculate_fitness(population):
    fitness_scores = []

    for individual in population:
        # Group the rows in 3's according to the columns.
        proj_a = individual[  : 3,1]  # First 3 rows, column 1.
        proj_b = individual[ 3: 6,2]  # Next  3 rows, column 2, etc.
        proj_c = individual[ 6: 9,3]
        proj_d = individual[ 9:12,4]
        proj_e = individual[12:15,5]  # Bottom 3 rows, last column.

        arr = np.array([proj_a, proj_b, proj_c, proj_d, proj_e])

        mean = arr.mean()          # Mean.
        std  = np.abs(arr.std())   # Standard deviation.

        # We want both the lowest mean and lowest standard deviation.
        # For simplicity, let's just add them and use that as the score.
        fitness_scores.append(mean + std)

    # Invert and scale the values so they can be used as weights
    # for random selection.
    fitness_scores  = np.array(fitness_scores)
    fitness_scores  = (fitness_scores.max() + .3 ) - fitness_scores
    fitness_scores /= (fitness_scores.max() + .07)
    fitness_scores *= 100

    return fitness_scores
```

Output - the first 3 rows belong to A, the next 3 to B and so forth:

```
employee proj_A proj_B proj_C proj_D proj_E
      A3      1      2      4      3      5
      C4      1      2      3      4      5
      A1      1      5      3      4      2
      C2      3      1      2      5      4
      B5      2      1      3      5      4
      C5      2      1      4      5      4
      A2      4      2      1      3      5
      A5      1      3      2      5      4
      B3      2      3      1      5      4
      B1      5      4      1      2      3
      C3      5      3      4      1      2
      C1      2      3      4      1      5
      B2      4      5      3      2      1
      B4      5      3      4      2      1
      A4      4      5      3      2      1
```

In this grouping it seems everyone is very happy and it's probably the optimal mix.

Here everyone is extremely happy with all 1's except A3 who gets a 3.

```
employee proj_A proj_B proj_C proj_D proj_E
      C4      1      _      _      _      _
      A1      1      _      _      _      _
      A5      1      _      _      _      _
      B5      _      1      _      _      _
      C2      _      1      _      _      _
      C5      _      1      _      _      _
      A2      _      _      1      _      _
      B3      _      _      1      _      _
      B1      _      _      1      _      _
      C1      _      _      _      1      _
      A3      _      _      _      3      _
      C3      _      _      _      1      _
      A4      _      _      _      _      1
      B4      _      _      _      _      1
      B2      _      _      _      _      1
```

I found that adjusting for a high rate of mutation, and protecting the top 5 individuals from mutation and death greatly improves the results.

Parents are selected by taking 4 individuals randomly using their fitness scores as weights to prefer higher fitness parents. The top of the 4 is then matched against any of the others that doesn't have an identical fitness score to try and prevent inbreeding and keep the population diversity in a good range.

Each iteration, one individual dies, two parents are selected and produce a child, and at a 50% rate an individual is selected and mutated by randomly swapping a couple of its rows.

The population I've found best is 150 members, and 1k to 2k iterations seems to get consistent results.

Comment: @ShivamSahil, have you taken into consideration that each project may require a different number of heads/seats? Or other factors like project manager preferences, or teammates that you wouldn't want to pair with eachother, or teammate preferences on other teammates? I'm thinking in terms of a more generalized solution.

Comment: Initial problem didn't had that part. Number of members were fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The question describes a variation of the "stable marriage problem". Which has a pretty simple algorithm; I pasted in the simplest version below - there are other versions that are more stringent. Suitors who aren't engaged, propose to the other party, which either rejects or accepts (removing their current engagement). This goes on until all parties are engaged.

```
# Gale-Shapley algorithm:
algorithm stable_matching is
    Initialize all m ∈ M and w ∈ W to free
    while ∃ free man m who still has a woman w to propose to do
        w := first woman on m`s list to whom m has not yet proposed
        if w is free then
            (m, w) become engaged
        else some pair (m`, w) already exists
            if w prefers m to m` then
                m` becomes free
                (m, w) become engaged 
            else
                (m`, w) remain engaged
            end if
        end if
    repeat
```

Modelling a project distribution solution after the stable marriage problem, we can treat the `Teammate`s as the suitors, and the other party as the polygamous `Project`, which can be engaged to more than one suitor. This may seem like a lot of code, but it's relatively short and easy to follow.

If the above algorithm is followed exactly, the project distributions may contain the 3rd or 4th picks of some of the teammates - which isn't a desirable situation. So, I found that randomizing the order of assignments and retrying several times while keeping track of the best distribution produced the best results.

*Each time this is run, it will likely produce an equivalently scored project distribution, but with teammates arranged differently. So if a teammate decides they don't like the 1 or 2 pick for some reason, just generate a new distribution.*

Runnable code at: https://pastebin.com/kVj0FuJP

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import cycle
from random import randint, shuffle
from statistics import mean, stdev

class Teammate:
    def __init__(self, identifier, projects, rankings):
        self._id        = identifier
        self._projects  = list(projects)
        self._rankings  = dict(zip(projects, rankings))
        self._prefs     = self.gen_project_preferences_cycle()
        self._project   = None

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    def rank(self, project):
        return self._rankings[project]

    @property
    def state(self):
        return 'ENGAGED' if self._project else 'FREE'

    def propose(self, project):
        return project.consider(self)

    def engage(self, project):
        self._project = project
        project.add(self)

    def disengage(self, project):
        self._project = None
        project.remove(self)

    @property
    def project_preferences(self):
        return self._prefs

    def gen_project_preferences_cycle(self):
        """ Returns a generator for a cyclical list of preferences in 
        order.
        """
        prefs = sorted(self._projects, key=self.rank)
        if randint(0, 1):
            prefs.insert(0, prefs[1])
        return cycle(prefs)

    def reset(self):
        self._project = None
        self._prefs   = self.gen_project_preferences_cycle()
```

By randomly assigning the second pick to the front of some `Teammate`'s preference lists, we get an interesting effect on the placements. By starting some teammates off on their 2nd pick, it's likely they're going to get bumped out of their 2nd choice and then find another project they rated 1. The net effect is you get matrices with mostly 1's, a small fraction of 2's, and no 3's and 4's.

The more interesting method of the `Project` class is the `consider()` method where the `Project` considers the engagement proposal of a `Teammate`. The fickle Project will cast aside any engaged suitor in its set of current suitors, if another comes along with a better offer.

```
class Project:
    def __init__(self, identifier, seats):
        self._id    = identifier
        self._seats = seats
        self._team  = []

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def score(self):
        return sum(tm.rank(self) for tm in self._team)

    def consider(self, teammate):
        """ Consider a proposal, have the Teammate establish the engagement
        if accepted, then return True; otherwise return False.
        """
        rank    = teammate.rank(self)
        team    = self._team
        seats   = self._seats
        if len(team) < seats or any(rank < tm.rank(self) for tm in team):
            # Either there's a seat available, or the newcomer has a better
            # offer than one of the current suitors.
            if len(team) >= seats:
                shuffle(team)
                tm_out = max(team, key=lambda tm: tm.rank(self))
                tm_out.disengage(self)  # Hit the road Jack...
            teammate.engage(self)  # What? and no ring!?...
            return True
        return False

    def add(self, teammate):
        self._team.append(teammate)

    def remove(self, teammate):
        self._team.remove(teammate)

    def clear(self):
        self._team = []

    @property
    def state(self):
        return 'FREE' if len(self._team) < self._seats else 'ENGAGED'

    @property
    def roster(self):
        self._team.sort(key=lambda tm: tm.id)
        return f"{self.id}: {[(tm.id, tm.rank(self)) for tm in self._team]}"
```

Of course, in the modern world everyone is using matchmaking services, and so do the `Teammate`s and `Projects`... The service is a bit quirky though and relies to some extent on random tries until it finds the best matchings for all parties.

```
class ProjectMatcher:
    def __init__(self, projects, teammates):
        self._projects  = projects
        self._teammates = teammates

    def match(self, num_iterations=1000):
        best_score   = 99999
        best_distrib = None

        for _ in range(num_iterations):
            # This is the piece that does the actual matching. You can 
            # see each line corresponds to a step in the Gale-Shapely
            # algorithm. You can find the details of some steps within
            # the Teammate and Project methods.               

            for teammate in self.gen_free_teammates_cycle():
                for project in teammate.project_preferences:
                    accepted = teammate.propose(project)
                    if accepted:
                        break

            # Determine if this distribution is the best so far.
            if self.evaluate() < best_score:
                best_score   = self.evaluate()
                best_distrib = deepcopy(self._projects)

            # Get ready for another round of matchmaking.
            self.reset()

        # Print out the best distribution of assignments found.
        print("PROJECT ASSIGNMENTS:")
        for project in best_distrib:
            print(f"    {project.roster}")

    def evaluate(self):
        # Determine the quality of the project assignments. We want a
        # low average score, preferably without outliers.
        s = [p.score for p in self._projects]
        m = mean(s)
        d = stdev(s, m)
        return m + d

    def gen_free_teammates_cycle(self):
        """ Returns a cyclical generator of the list of Teammates that are
        still unengaged.
        """
        teammates = list(self._teammates)
        shuffle(teammates)
        while any(tm.state == 'FREE' for tm in teammates):
            for tm in teammates:
                if tm.state == 'FREE':
                    yield tm
            shuffle(teammates)

    def reset(self):
        [p.clear() for p in self._projects]
        [t.reset() for t in self._teammates]

    @staticmethod
    def from_dataframe(df):
        n_seats   = len(df.values) // (len(df.columns) - 1)
        projects  = [Project(proj, n_seats) for proj in df.columns[1:]]
        teammates = [Teammate(tm[0], projects, tm[1:]) for tm in df.values]
        return ProjectMatcher(projects, teammates)
```

And to put it all together...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
    employee  proj_A  proj_B  proj_C  proj_D  proj_E
          A1       1       5       3       4       2
          B1       5       4       1       2       3
          C1       2       3       4       1       5
          A2       4       2       1       3       5
          B2       4       5       3       2       1
          C2       3       1       2       5       4
          A3       1       2       4       3       5
          B3       2       3       1       5       4
          C3       5       3       4       1       2
          A4       4       5       3       2       1
          B4       5       3       4       2       1
          C4       1       2       3       4       5
          A5       1       3       2       5       4
          B5       2       1       3       5       4
          C5       2       1       4       5       4
      """), sep=r'\s+')

    pm = ProjectMatcher.from_dataframe(df)

    pm.match()
```

Output:

```
$ python projectmatcher.py 
PROJECT ASSIGNMENTS:
    proj_A: [('A1', 1), ('A3', 1), ('C4', 1)]
    proj_B: [('B5', 1), ('C2', 1), ('C5', 1)]
    proj_C: [('A2', 1), ('A5', 2), ('B3', 1)]
    proj_D: [('B1', 2), ('C1', 1), ('C3', 1)]
    proj_E: [('A4', 1), ('B2', 1), ('B4', 1)]
```

The results are consistently good with maybe 100 iterations, it defaults to 1K for good measure, which only takes a blink of the eye. Somehow it manages to produce high quality matchings despite being based partly on chance.

The program can be modified to collect all the unique distributions that have the lowest score and generate a list. Each of these had the same lowest score, but the distributions are different:

```
PROJECT ASSIGNMENTS:
    option 1
        proj_A: [('A3', 1), ('A5', 1), ('C4', 1)]
        proj_B: [('B5', 1), ('C2', 1), ('C5', 1)]
        proj_C: [('A2', 1), ('B1', 1), ('B3', 1)]
        proj_D: [('B4', 2), ('C1', 1), ('C3', 1)]
        proj_E: [('A1', 2), ('A4', 1), ('B2', 1)]
    option 2
        proj_A: [('A3', 1), ('A5', 1), ('C4', 1)]
        proj_B: [('B5', 1), ('C2', 1), ('C5', 1)]
        proj_C: [('A2', 1), ('B1', 1), ('B3', 1)]
        proj_D: [('A4', 2), ('C1', 1), ('C3', 1)]
        proj_E: [('A1', 2), ('B2', 1), ('B4', 1)]
    option 3
        proj_A: [('A1', 1), ('A3', 1), ('C4', 1)]
        proj_B: [('B5', 1), ('C2', 1), ('C5', 1)]
        proj_C: [('A2', 1), ('A5', 2), ('B3', 1)]
        proj_D: [('B1', 2), ('C1', 1), ('C3', 1)]
        proj_E: [('A4', 1), ('B2', 1), ('B4', 1)]
    option 4
        proj_A: [('A3', 1), ('A5', 1), ('C4', 1)]
        proj_B: [('B5', 1), ('C2', 1), ('C5', 1)]
        proj_C: [('A2', 1), ('B1', 1), ('B3', 1)]
        proj_D: [('B2', 2), ('C1', 1), ('C3', 1)]
        proj_E: [('A1', 2), ('A4', 1), ('B4', 1)]
```